# How to perform an action when receiving tokens in smart contract

Tags: tokens, react, smart-contract-wallets, transfer, binance-smart-chain

So I have some custom Tokens in a smart contract and whenever I receive BUSD in the smart contract I want to be able to send some of the custom Tokens back to the user that paid through a button from the front-end (done in react)

I have tried this with BNB and the receive() function and it works perfectly!! however I cannot seem to be able to do this with BUSD as it doesn't fire the receive() function! are there any work-arounds for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that with an ERC-20/BEP-20 token. ERC-777 tokens solve that problem by implementing the `tokensReceived` fallback function, unfortunately, there are not many tokens using it. https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-777

Comment: I see! thank you! are there any workarounds for this then or are we stuck in a sense?